# find exclude multiple directories - z/OS USS Region

Tags: find

On z/OS (Mainframe version 2.1) Unix System Services region, I am trying to execute this a command that involves find like so:

let's say I have the following directory structure:

```
/tmp
    /dir1-include
    /dir2-exclude
    /dir3-include
    /dir4-exclude
```

I am trying to get a count of all the files older than 90 days in `dir1-include` and `dir3-include`. This following command doesn't seem to work:

```
find /tmp/ \( -path /dir2-exclude -prune -o \
                  -path /dir4-exclude -prune \
               \) \
               -o -type f -mtime +90 | wc -l
```

It gives me:

```
FSUM6372 Unknown option "-path"
Usage: find directory ... expression`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's many ways to do this. All of the options below worked on z/OS.

If your `find` doesn't support `-path`, and since you're assuming no filenames will contain newlines (by piping to `wc`), you could work around it with `grep`:

```
find /tmp/ -type f -mtime +90 | grep -v /tmp/dir2-exclude | grep -v /tmp/dir4-exclude | wc -l
```

If your excluded directories share a pattern (that doesn't exclude anything you want to keep), you could simplify it to:

```
find /tmp ... | grep -cv '/tmp/dir.*-exclude'
```

... again with the understanding that this will mis-count the output from find if there are directories or filenames with newlines in them.

If your `find` supports multiple starting paths, and the ones you want to include share a pattern, you could work around it that way:

```
find /tmp/dir*-include -type f -mtime +90 | wc -l
```

Also, -prune option doesn't descend below the mentioned directories.

```
find /tmp/ -type d -name "/dir2-exclude" -prune -o -type d -name "/dir4-exclude" -prune -o -type f -mtime +90 | wc -l
```